# Google dictionary Spelling check in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, dictionary, toast, android-toast

How to check spell using `Google dictionary` in android?

I want to know that the word type by me is correct or not.
It should check from `Google dictionary`.
If the word is correct then it should be shown in toast else it shouldn't be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
   public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
      final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     boolean isSpellCorrect = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i) {
         // Returned suggestions are contained in SuggestionsInfo
         final int len = arg0[i].getSuggestionsCount();
         if(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(arg0[i].getSuggestionAt(i)))
         {
             isSpellCorrect = true;
             Toast.makeText(this, "Entered word is correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             break;
         }
      }
   }
```

Use this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spelling_checker.htm) for whole project just make changes in above method.